# Create captive runtime of AIR application for MacOS, but on Windows

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm developing an AIR application in Flex on Windows. When I build it as captive runtime it only creates the .exe executable for Windows (I am developing on Windows), but I also need an executable for MacOS.

How do I do that in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [Hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/).  Basically, you'll need to run Mac OSX in a virtual machine from your Windows Platform.

I'm pretty sure this is against the Apple Licensing Agreement; and it is likely that you'll need to either use the command line tools or buy a Mac specific license of Flash Builder.

Comment: So if I compile it on a Mac, can I just copy an executable from Mac version and drop it in the same directory and the app will be executable on both systems? I need to make a pendrive with this application for both systems.

Comment: Drop the "executable version from Mac" in the same directory as what?  On Macs you need a DMG to run; on Windows you need an exe.  Correspondingly you can only create a Captive Runtime DMG on a Mac; and a exe captive runtime on Windows.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes--if you include the .app file (directory) on your disk/drive, it will be executable when you're on a Mac.  (Side-by-side .exe/.app, or, if you want installers, .exe/(.pkg/.dmg) files.)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know. I just wanted the same directory with application contents to contain executables for both Windows and Mac.